# Java Request Date Validation: For any class with two variable parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I am creating a shared component for Request Date constraints, Begin Date is before End Date.
I want to take my current Validation request,  and make it common, so I type in the (Begin and EndDate class members for any Class), and it will work. How can this be done? I use annotations above the request class, in ProductRequest below .

Note: How do I set Start and End date parameters in the annotation; they may not always be "Start/End" field members, sometimes they could be "Begin/Finish" in another class .

```
@DatesRequestConstraint
public class ProductRequest {
    private Long productId;
    private DateTime startDate;
    private DateTime EndDate;
    private List<String> productStatus;
}

@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface DatesRequestConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid dates request.";
    Class <?> [] groups() default {};
    Class <? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};
}

public class ProductValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DatesRequestConstraint, ProductRequest> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatesRequestConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ProductRequest productRequest, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    if (productRequest.getStartDate() != null && 
        productRequest.getEndDate() != null && 
        productRequest.getStartDate().isAfter(productRequest.getEndDate())) {
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. Implement `ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, Object>` so that you can apply the `@DatesMatch` annotation on any type;
2. Add custom `String` fields to the `@DatesMatch` annotation where you can specify the names of the fields you want to validate;
3. Use reflection at runtime to access the field values by their specified name.

There's a similar example of class-level validation over multiple custom fields here: [Baeldung: Spring MVC Custom Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#custom-class-level-validation) (scroll down to "9. Custom Class Level Validation").

Customized to your example, something like this should work:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = DatesMatchValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DatesMatch {
    String message() default "The dates don't match.";
    String startField();
    String endField();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        DatesMatch[] value();
    }
}

// Accept a list of items so that you can validate more than one pair of dates on the same object if needed
@DatesMatch.List({
        @DatesMatch(
                startField = "startDate",
                endField = "endDate",
                message = "The end date must be after the start date."
        )
})
public class ProductRequest {
    private Long productId;
    private Instant startDate;
    private Instant endDate;
    private List<String> productStatus;
    /* Getters and setters omitted */
}

public class DatesMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, Object> {
    private String startField;
    private String endField;

    public void initialize(DatesMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        this.startField = constraintAnnotation.startField();
        this.endField = constraintAnnotation.endField();
    }

    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Instant startFieldValue = (Instant) new BeanWrapperImpl(value)
                .getPropertyValue(startField);
        Instant endFieldValue = (Instant) new BeanWrapperImpl(value)
                .getPropertyValue(endField);

        if (startFieldValue == null || endFieldValue == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return endFieldValue.isAfter(startFieldValue);
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** (in response to comment):

> this answer is great, allows multiple pair of dates, however isn't type-string safe, person can type in whatever for the fields in the product fields

Implementing `ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, Object>` is meant as an easy catch-all solution you can apply to any class.

But you can absolutely do it in a more type-safe way by implementing a separate `ConstraintValidator` for each type you want to validate (i.e. `ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, ProductRequest>`, `ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, AnotherRequest>`, ...) and then specify all of them in the `@Constraint(validatedBy={...})` attribute:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ProductRequestDatesMatchValidator.class, AnotherRequestDatesMatchValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DatesMatch {

    String message() default "Invalid dates request.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

@DatesMatch(message = "Start and end dates do not match!")
public class ProductRequest {
    private Long productId;
    private Instant startDate;
    private Instant endDate;
    private List<String> productStatus;
    /* Getters and setters omitted */
}

@DatesMatch(message = "Begin and finish dates do not match!")
public class AnotherRequest {
    private Long productId;
    private Instant beginDate;
    private Instant finishDate;
    private List<String> productStatus;
    /* Getters and setters omitted */
}

public class ProductRequestDatesMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, ProductRequest> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ProductRequest value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // No need to cast here
        Instant startDate = value.getStartDate();
        Instant endDate = value.getEndDate();

        // You could reuse this logic between each implementation by putting it in a parent class or a utility method
        if (startDate == null || endDate == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return startDate.isBefore(endDate);
    }
}

public class AnotherRequestDatesMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DatesMatch, AnotherRequest> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(AnotherRequest value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Instant beginDate = value.getBeginDate();
        Instant finishDate = value.getFinishDate();

        if (beginDate == null || finishDate == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return beginDate.isBefore(finishDate);
    }
}
```

Do note, however, that this is still not compile-time type-safe, as you could put the `@DatesMatch` annotation on a class for which you haven't written an implementation and the validation will only fail at runtime.

(You could achieve compile-time type-safety using annotation processing, but this another topic for another time.)

Comment: this works! I would change this line,          if (startFieldValue != null && endFieldValue != null &
                startFieldValue.isAfter(endFieldValue)) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: this answer is great, allows multiple pair of dates,  however isn't type-string safe, person can type in whatever for the fields in the product fields, both answers are helpful

Comment: please remember to upvote question also, thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example regarding the type-safety

Comment: I like your first method better, what Im saying is a person in the original method can type anything for field names, and compiler would not catch it, however the new solution, only allows 1 pair of dates it seems, no method is perfect, given limits of java library, appreciate answers

Answer (score 5):

You can annotate startDate and endDate with custom annotations something like:

```
@StartDateField
private DateTime startDate;
@EndDateField
private DateTime endDate;
```

Then in your `isValid()`, you can access both startDate and endDate fields by their annotations by iterating over all class fields (in your case, all ProductRequest fields) and checking the following:

```
field.isAnnotationPresent(StartDateField.class)
field.isAnnotationPresent(EndDateField.class)
```

The complete code could be as follows:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({ ANNOTATION_TYPE.TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductValidator.class)
@Documented
@interface DatesRequestConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid dates request.";
    Class <?> [] groups() default {};
    Class <? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};
}

@DatesRequestConstraint
class ProductRequest {
    private Long productId;
    @StartDateField
    private DateTime startDate;
    @EndDateField
    private DateTime EndDate;
    private List<String> productStatus;
}

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@interface StartDateField {
}

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@interface EndDateField {
}

public class ProductValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DatesRequestConstraint, Object> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatesRequestConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object requestObject, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        DateTime startDate = getDateFieldByAnnotation(requestObject, StartDateField.class);
        DateTime endDate = getDateFieldByAnnotation(requestObject, EndDateField.class);
        if (startDate != null &&
                endDate != null &&
                startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }

    private DateTime getDateFieldByAnnotation(Object requestObject, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {
        return Arrays.stream(requestObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)).map(field -> {
            try {
                return field.get(requestObject);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }).map(DateTime.class::cast).findAny().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mattsmith5 I have just added the complete code example.

Comment: this is awesome, does it accept more than 1 pair of dates?

Comment: as per the provided code, no. It could be only one pair per class.